# Show the expected return of the portfolio and how to derive return variance of the long-short portfolio?

Tags: portfolio, variance, longshort

[image]

Show the expected return of the portfolio and how to derive the return variance of the long-short portfolio? (see picture)

Comment: For this type of question it is expected you show some form of attempt, or existing knowledge, rather than just paste the question and expect someone to do it for you.